# Store a video in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, video, storage

I have to store a video into an Oracle database. I just would like to know what are the possible ways to do it and if there are any references I can get based on? Unfortunately, there is not much information about such practice.

I am not sure if the right way is to use SQL loader to load the video from a file.

Comment: There's no any difference what is the data format. You may store any file in blob by writing a binary stream into it from your application side.

Comment: i actually come a long a tutorial which uses the sql loader to insert a picture as blob type , so you are saying i can do the same thing with the video (mp4 type)

Comment: @amilana - Yes.  If you want to insert any type of file into a `blob` column, you can follow the same `SQL*Loader` process you'd use to load an image into a `blob`.  There are likely other approaches as well depending on the exact nature of the problem you're trying to solve (i.e. Are you loading one file once?  Are you loading a number of files once a night?  Are you trying to load files interactively in an application?)